# Is $\mathbb{C}$ projective as a $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^3,y^3,xy)$-module?

Tags: homological-algebra, projective-module

Let $R = \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, and $I = (x^3, y^3, xy)$ be the ideal of $R$ generated by $x^3, y^3, xy$. Is it true that the $R/I$-module $\mathbb{C}$ (with the natural action) is a projective module? I think it is, but am not sure how to prove (nor disprove) this. I suspect that in fact $\mathbb{C}$ is a direct summand of $R/I$ and this has been my main line of attack, but I can't prove it (though of course this may not be the case even if $\mathbb{C}$ were a projective module).

Comment: What is the 'natural action' of $R/I$ on $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: I am thinking of $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x,y)$ here, and I mean the usual multiplication action. Of course when I say $\mathbb{C}$ being a direct summand of $R/I$, I mean I was trying to find modules isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ that are direct summands of $R/I$. I'm sorry for not having clarified this earlier!

Comment: How does (for example) $x^2 + y^2 + (x^3,y^3,xy)$ act on $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: It is clear that $R/I$ is a $\Bbb{C}$-module with multiplication as the action.  It's not clear that $\Bbb{C}$ is an $R/I$-module : what element of $\Bbb{C}$ is $x \cdot \mathrm{i}$?

Comment: Eric Towers, user259242, sorry about spoiling your efforts in trying to extract the definition of an $R/I$-action on $\Bbb{C}$ from the asker. I missed that identifying the action was an integral part of the question and just gave it away. Well, the Yellow Feline apparently knew how it goes anyway :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Are you sure about that? There is no 'natural' multiplication action here, as YellowCat claims.

Comment: Thanks all! The action I am thinking of is indeed the action of $R/I$ on $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x,y)$ (see my previous comment), as @JyrkiLahtonen has mentioned in his answer below. I apologize for using the term "natural action" - maybe it isn't the most natural, and I should have been less lazy and made myself clearer.

Comment: @user259242: The ideal $M=(x,y)\subset R$ is the only maximal ideal containing $I$, so I don't see any alternatives to identifying $\Bbb{C}$ with $R/M$, and the latter is surely naturally an $R/I$-module. IMHO that is natural: $(p(x,y)+I)\cdot z=p(0,0)z$ for all $p(x,y)\in R$, $z\in \Bbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from first principles (undoubtedly there are more enlightening ways of looking at this, but let's go with minimal technology). Let me put the ball on the tee for you.

Let $M$ be the ideal of $R$ generated by $x$ and $y$. The natural way to think of $\Bbb{C}$ as an $R/I$-module is IMHO to think of it as $\Bbb{C}=R/M$. Here $I\subset M$, so $R/M$ is naturally an $R/I$-module.

We have the natural surjection $\pi:R/I\to \Bbb{C}$ defined by $\pi(p(x,y)+I)=p(0,0)$. Explain the following:

1. $\pi$ is a homomorphism of $R/I$-modules.
2. $\Bbb{C}=R/M$ is a projective $R/I$-module if and only if $\pi$ splits. IOW iff there exists a homomorphism of $R/I$-modules $s:\Bbb{C}\to R/I$ such that $\pi\circ s= id_{\Bbb{C}}.$
3. Such a homomorphism is fully determined if we know $s(1)=r(x,y)+I$.
4. The polynomial $r(x,y)$ must satisfy the constraints: A) $r(0,0)=1$, B) $xr(x,y)\in I$, C) $yr(x,y)\in I$.
5. We have $$R/I=\{a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+b_1y+b_2y^2+I\mid a_0,a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2\in\Bbb{C}\}$$ and all the cosets of $I$ have a unique representative of that form.
6. There does not exist an element $r(x,y)+I\in R/I$ satisfying all the constraints 3A/B/C.
7. The required splitting homomorphism does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The trivial module is never projective in situations of this form. One can prove that the $\mathbb C$-vector space $\operatorname{Tor}_1^R(\mathbb C,\mathbb C)$ identifies with the vector space of generators of $R$, which in this case has dimension $2$, and is in particular non-zero. In fact, you can show that in your case $\operatorname{Tor}_n^R(\mathbb C,\mathbb C) = 2^n$ for each $n\geqslant 0$.